# Error when launching PackageMaker (Xcode 4): "PackageMaker cannot be opened..."

Tags: macos, crash, xcode, package-maker

When I try to launch PackageMaker.app, it immediately crashes with the error:

```
PackageMaker cannot be opened because of a problem.
```

Specs:

- Xcode 4
- Mac OS X 10.8.1 Mountain Lion
- MacBook Pro

I've also posted this in [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4306850).

Comment: Can you give us a little more information? Has it always been like that? What's your Xcode version? Have you repaired permissions from Disk Utility, anything else?

Comment: No, I first encountered this error after upgrading to Xcode 4. My Xcode version? Xcode 4, dunno the subversion right now as I'm booted into Windows. Permissions *could* be the issue, dunno.